# Replace very small numbers by zero in the output of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, precision-and-accuracy, faq

I have a long nested list, but many elements are numbers of order `10^-18` or less, e.g.

```
{{0.217548, -0.217548, -0.0373272, -9.83823*10^-18, -8.13807*10^-19}, \
{0.217548, 0.217548, 0.0373272, 7.54332*10^-18, 6.23849*10^-19}, \
{0.183095, 0.0504041, 0.00207916, -0.214279, -0.0218996}, \
{0.985472, -0.193791, -0.461242, 4.17611*10^-20, 1.22184*10^-20}, \
{0.985472, 0.193791, 0.461242, -1.18329*10^-30, -9.86076*10^-31}, 
{0.60405, 9.7862*10^-23, -9.11593*10^-24, -1.54354*10^-22, -1.91278*10^-23}, \
{0.80994, 0.556147, 0.623645, 0.558531, 0.625958}}
```

Then, to make the output more readable, I want to print in the output the numbers with absolute value smaller than `10^-18` as zeros.

What is the smartest and fastest way to do this?

Comment: How about `N[results, precision]` (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html)?

Comment: If dealing with reals, `Chop` your list. The second argument defines the threshold for zero.

Comment: @YvesKlett Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Why don´t you provide a sample list in your question? That would be instructive. BTW, not sure if this is not a duplicate or too localized (we´ll see).

Comment: Perhaps you should also change the question title a bit, since you are not really after the precision but a simple chopping (at least my answer assumes that).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is rather basic ,but since it helped you, I´ll post the answer and leave it to the other users to judge.

The second argument to [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Chop.html) (see *Details* section)  defines the magnitude below which values will be replaced by 0.

```
l = {{0.217548, -0.217548, -0.0373272, -9.83823*10^-18, \
-8.13807*10^-19}, {0.217548, 0.217548, 0.0373272, 7.54332*10^-18, 
    6.23849*10^-19}, {0.183095, 0.0504041, 
    0.00207916, -0.214279, -0.0218996}, {0.985472, -0.193791, \
-0.461242, 4.17611*10^-20, 1.22184*10^-20}, {0.985472, 0.193791, 
    0.461242, -1.18329*10^-30, -9.86076*10^-31}, {0.60405, 
    9.7862*10^-23, -9.11593*10^-24, -1.54354*10^-22, \
-1.91278*10^-23}, {0.80994, 0.556147, 0.623645, 0.558531, 0.625958}};

Chop[l, 10^-18]
```

> {{0.217548, -0.217548, -0.0373272, -9.83823*10^-18, 0},
>     {0.217548, 0.217548, 0.0373272, 7.54332*10^-18, 0},
>     {0.183095, 0.0504041, 0.00207916, -0.214279, -0.0218996},
>     {0.985472, -0.193791, -0.461242, 0, 0},
>     {0.985472, 0.193791, 0.461242, 0, 0},
>     {0.60405, 0, 0, 0, 0},
>   {0.80994, 0.556147, 0.623645, 0.558531, 0.625958}}

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [`Threshold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Threshold.html):

```
l = {{0.217548, -0.217548, -0.0373272, -9.83823*10^-18, -8.13807*10^-19},
     {0.217548, 0.217548, 0.0373272, 7.54332*10^-18,  6.23849*10^-19},
     {0.183095, 0.0504041,  0.00207916, -0.214279, -0.0218996}, 
     {0.985472, -0.193791, -0.461242, 4.17611*10^-20, 1.22184*10^-20},
     {0.985472, 0.193791,  0.461242, -1.18329*10^-30, -9.86076*10^-31}, 
     {0.60405,  9.7862*10^-23, -9.11593*10^-24, -1.54354*10^-22, -1.91278*10^-23}, 
     {0.80994, 0.556147, 0.623645, 0.558531, 0.625958}};

Threshold[l, 10^-18] (* or Threshold[l,{"Hard",10^18}] *)

(* {{0.217548, -0.217548, -0.0373272, -9.83823*10^-18, 0.},
     {0.217548,  0.217548, 0.0373272, 7.54332*10^-18, 0.}, 
     {0.183095, 0.0504041, 0.00207916, -0.214279, -0.0218996},
     {0.985472, -0.193791, -0.461242,  0., 0.},
     {0.985472, 0.193791, 0.461242, 0., 0.}, 
     {0.60405, 0., 0.,  0., 0.}, 
     {0.80994, 0.556147, 0.623645, 0.558531, 0.625958}} *)
```

FWIW, it seems to be faster than `Chop` for large lists:

```
 dt = RandomReal[1, {1000000}, WorkingPrecision -> 40];
 dtchp = Chop[dt, 10^-18]; // AbsoluteTiming
 (* {0.3110311,Null}*)
 dtthrshld = Threshold[dt, 10^-18]; // AbsoluteTiming
 (* {0.240023,Null} *)
 dtchp == dtthrshld
 (* True *)
```

Comment: My machine puts `Chop` slight in front of `Threshold` with altered precision (and using real `10.^-18` helps as well), while `Threshold` smokes `Chop` for standard precision - any explanations?

Comment: @Yves, good observation (confirmed on Version 9 Windows Vista 64bit). Don't have any idea why, though.

Comment: @YvesKlett probable explanation is that `Chop` replaces the values with exact zero, which involves unpacking the list if packed to start with. `Threshold` uses a machine zero and doesn't need to unpack. Since arbitrary precision values can't be stored in packed arrays anyway, `Chop` and `Threshold` are going to be similar in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The solutions above would be also my choice, but to give a more complete picture, here is an additional approach.

This generates the list with small valuse and those about a unity:

```
lst = Table[RandomReal[{-2, 2}]*10^RandomReal[{-10, 1}], {45}]
```

this solves the task replacing items smaller than 10^-5:

```
lst /. x_ /; Abs[x] <= 10^-5 -> 0
```

This is the result:

```
 {-0.00716429, -0.0364071, -0.000281284, 0, -0.000856377, 0, 0.164907, \
-0.0516522, -0.000840723, 0, 0.0467477, -12.1348, -0.636598, \
-0.0000171288, 0, 0, 0, 0.0910157, -0.0000228134, 0, 0, -0.396028, 0, \
0, 0, 0, -0.129861, -0.000599652, 0, 0, -0.00824202, 0, 0, 0.0181993, \
-0.0000162593, 0.00320663, -0.248421, 0, 0, 0, 0.0031162, 0.0363161, \
0.0216937, 0, 0}
```

Comment: May I ask a question? Is there any alternative to display two decimal places without AccountForm? I follow your advice and append "AccountForm" in front of the expression AccountingForm[lst /. x_ /; Abs[x] <= 10^-4 -> 0, 2]
e.g {0.342416, 0.304959, 0, 0.352625} -> {0.34, 0.3, 0, 0.35}

Comment: @Nelson Mok I am not quite sure to have understood your aim. I have the impression that just for visualization you would like to have a shorted representation of the terms in the list, say, with two figures after comma, right? If yes, you may use the `NumberForm` function in such a way: `lst = Table[RandomReal[{-2, 2}]*10^RandomReal[{-10, 1}], {45}]; lst1 = lst /. x_ /; Abs[x] <= 10^-5 -> 0; Map[NumberForm[#, {3, 2}] &, lst1]` . Have fun!

Comment: thank you, your suggest resolved the problem.