# How to prevent tiny complex errors in Integrate?

Tags: numerical-integration, complex

Integrate is adding a tiny imaginary error to an easy result.  Why?  And how can I stop it?

```
gauMix[x_, means_, vars_] := 
  Total[(E^-(((x - means)^2)/(2*vars)))/Sqrt[2*Pi*vars]]/Length[means];
means = {-7, 7};
vars = {6, 6.5};
f[x_] := gauMix[x, means, vars];
fxx = Integrate[f[x]*(x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]


(* 55.25 - 3.16199*10^-14 I  *)
```

If I change vars to {6,6} everything is fine. And NIntegrate hasn't made this error yet, that I've seen.  But I want to use Integrate instead of NIntegrate so I can get an exact, analytical answer.

Comment: How tiny? Try `Chop`.

Comment: @Kuba  I could try that, but I worry about WHY it's adding the error.  Is it a symptom of some other error?

Comment: To get a closed form solution, why not use: `Integrate[f[x] x^2, x]`

Comment: Not addressing why you see this particular behavior, but if you want an _exact_ analytic answer, you need exact inputs.  6.5 is not an exact number.

Comment: @chuy What do you mean "6.5 is not an exact number"??? It's exactly 6.5

Comment: @JerryGuern He means [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html).  Google for "mathematica inexact number".  `65/10` would be considered exact.  `Integrate` doesn't play well with inexact numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace very small numbers by zero in the output of a list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21674/replace-very-small-numbers-by-zero-in-the-output-of-a-list)

Comment: @m_goldberg  This is a similar but different problem in the MMa is adding an imaginary part that shouldn't be there, so the solution is completely different.

Comment: And why do SE users keep putting answers in the Comments instead of in the Answers?

Comment: Perhaps because these are not full answers? See also, http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/why-are-many-answers-posted-as-comments

Answer (score 9):

```
gauMix[x_, means_, vars_] := Total[(E^-(((x - means)^2)/(2*vars)))/Sqrt[2*Pi*vars]]/ Length[means];
means = {-7, 7};
vars = {6, 65/10};
f[x_] := gauMix[x, means, vars];
fxx = Integrate[f[x]*(x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* 221/4 *)
```